# My custom cell showed up previously in tableview, now it doesn't

Tags: xcode, tableview, custom-cell

Here's my issue. I have a custom cell with identifyer 'tweetCell' I have imported this into mt tableviewcontroller.h file. I have linked the class to the prototype cell in storyboard. All the UILabels are wired up to the cell but I cannot get the tableview to display the cell. It did work? Then overnight stopped?!! Can anyone spot my error here? Thanks in advance......

```
- (void)fetchTweets
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23mysearchhashtag"]];

        NSError* error;

        tweets = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                 options:kNilOptions
                                                   error:&error];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    });
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return tweets.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"tweetCell";

    customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[customCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSDictionary *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *tweetText = [tweet valueForKey:@"text"];

    NSArray *tweetComponents = [tweetText componentsSeparatedByString:@":"]; 


    cell.firstDetail.text = [tweetComponents objectAtIndex:0];
    cell.secondDetail.text = [tweetComponents objectAtIndex:1];
    cell.thirdDetail.text = [tweetComponents objectAtIndex:2];




    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I did not understand the upvoting concept - thank you for drawing it to my attention. I will look into this and action it on all the people who have helped.

Comment: Apparently voting up requires a 15 reputation so it will not let me do it

Comment: I'm glad you weren't offended at my constructive comments. Until you get to a score of 15 (which won't be that hard to do if you ask good questions or give great answers), the least you can do is "accept" (click the checkmark icon) next to the best answer in the questions you've previously asked.

Comment: I've just actioned what you suggested but unfortunately there is still no linkage from tableView to CustomCell...